# How to achieve 'wordwrap' of groupboxes in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I had a big explanation of what I wanted, until I realized that what I'm trying to reproduce is precisely word wrap, but with 200x150 groupboxes.

The only way I can figure to implement it would be to hardcode the positioning of the groupboxes on the resized event of the usercontrol (which I am getting going on right now). I'm wondering if there's another, easier, way that I might be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the correctly sized group boxes to a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203(loband).aspx).